# AutoHotKey App Crash

Tags: .net, windows, amazon-web-services, autohotkey

Running on an Amazon Workspace (Windows 7, Windows Server 2008).

I was running this simple AutoHotKey script, which left clicks the mouse at certain positions, over night on my machine and the next morning, I had a crash message. Does anyone know why this may be?

Code:

```
afterPlayedMiddle()
{
  Random, randomPlayEndPosition, 1386, 1391
  MouseClick, left, %randomPlayEndPosition%, 379
  Sleep, 12000
  skipPlay()
  Return
}

skipPlay()
{
  FileAppend,
  (
    1
  ), D:\Users\me\Desktop\log.txt
  Random, randomSkipSecondsPosition, 1208, 1326
  Random, randomPlayMiddleLength, 31000, 40000
  MouseClick, left, %randomSkipSecondsPosition%, 379
  Sleep, %randomPlayMiddleLength%
  afterPlayedMiddle()
  Return
}

skipPlay()
```

Error Details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: AutoHotkey.exe
  Application Version:  1.1.24.4
  Application Timestamp:    5854e399
  Fault Module Name:    AutoHotkey.exe
  Fault Module Version: 1.1.24.4
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5854e399
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0000000000037550
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0939
  Additional Information 2: 09391397756772fac27d80fc3911da27
  Additional Information 3: 3aa0
  Additional Information 4: 3aa056cf1d0cfdd807c97dd254e25a74

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our    privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program ran out of stack memory.

The error code `c00000fd` which is a define for `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW`.

You're calling your functions recursively, without returning. This crash can be replicated by the following program:

```
afterPlayedMiddle()
{
  skipPlay()
  Return
}

skipPlay()
{
  afterPlayedMiddle()
  Return
}

skipPlay()
```

You will have to structure your code differently. I suggest a loop calling both functions in sequence.